# Lyapunov function and asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, solution-verification

I just want to verify this problem. The instructions are below, but you have to consider the differential equation and some other information. I don't know how to type that information here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: con]

Comment: Please typeset the question instead of posting images.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I already post the instructions. Are below the problem solution. Is the las picture. also I posted more information about the problem. Sorry for it, but I just don't know how type it.